# What is the difference between Deformation technique and Ekeland's variational principle?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What is the difference between Deformation technique and  [Ekeland's variational principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekeland%27s_variational_principle) to approach [Mountain Pass  theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_pass_theorem) ?

Comment: Did you read both proofs?

Comment: @tomas yes for deformation i follow Evans book  pls give suggetion for read(book ) Ekeland variational principle. Now am reading "topic in sobolev spaces and applications" by D.bahuguna, v.raghavendra, b.v.rathish kumar.pls if you say the difference it will very helpful for me.Because it is little hard